# Implement caching in Sinatra app to handle twitter rate limits

Tags: ruby, caching, twitter, sinatra, rate-limiting

I have written a small Sinatra script to fetch 2 tweets of a user and display 10 retweeters in the descending order of their no. of followers:

Puzzle/puzzle.rb

```
require 'twitter'
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'
#require 'haml'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = ""
    config.consumer_secret     = ""
    config.access_token        = ""
    config.access_token_secret = ""
end

set :server, 'webrick'

set :haml, :format => :html5

get '/' do
  content_type :json
  arr = []
        retweeters = client.retweeters_of(429627812459593728)

        retweeters.each do |retweeter|
            ob = {}
            ob[:name] = retweeter.name
            ob[:followers_count] = retweeter.followers_count
            arr.push(ob)
        end


    # remove the duplicates and sort on the users with the most followers,
    sorted_influencers = arr.sort_by { |hsh| hsh[:followers_count] }
    sorted_influencers.reverse!
    sorted_influencers[0..9].to_s
end
```

I am trying to handle rate limits.

How to cache the json output to avoid rate limit exceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you keep your very simple scenario, you could use a small custom class to store the information and provide thread-safe methods (it is not clear from your question where your problem exactly resides, but this one problem will arise anyway):

```
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'
require 'date'
require 'thread'
require 'twitter'

set :server, 'webrick'

set :haml, :format => :html5

class MyCache
  def initialize()
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    @last_update = DateTime.new            # by default, -4732 BC
    @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ""
      config.consumer_secret     = ""
      config.access_token        = ""
      config.access_token_secret = ""
    end
  end

  def get_cache
    @mutex.synchronize do
      if DateTime.now - @last_update > 10.0 / (3600 * 24)
        @last_update = DateTime.now

        arr = []
        retweeters = @client.retweeters_of(429627812459593728)

        retweeters.each do |retweeter|
          ob = {}
          ob[:name] = retweeter.name
          ob[:followers_count] = retweeter.followers_count
          arr.push(ob)
        end

        # remove the duplicates and sort on the users with the most followers,
        sorted_influencers = arr.sort_by { |hsh| hsh[:followers_count] }
        sorted_influencers.reverse!
        @cache = sorted_influencers[0..9].to_s
      end

      @cache
    end
  end
end

my_cache = MyCache.new

get '/' do
  content_type :json
  my_cache.get_cache
end
```

This version now includes everything needed. I use the @client to store the instance of the twitter client (I suppose it's reusable), also note how the whole code is inside the `if` statement, and at last we update `@cache`. If you are unfamiliar with Ruby, the value of a block is determined by its last expression, so when I write `@cache` alone it is as if I had written `return @cache`.

Comment: I edited my code to show you how it can be called from within a route. One thing that you have to understand about Sinatra is that each request will be in a new "instance" context, so when you use instance variables inside a route, they do not persist until the next call (and if you have two users calling the same page at the same time, the instance variables are obviously different).

Comment: Why am I getting this error  `<class:MyCache>': undefined method `get' for MyCache:Class (NoMethodError)  ?

Comment: I edited my answer to have a filly working piece of code, also I had forgotten to update `@last_update` but now it's done properly. If you run it you'll see a new timestamp but only every ten seconds. Inserting your own code to query the twitter API should be exclusively in the `if` clause.

Comment: Thanks @user846250 ! It is giving the required output in every 10 sec also rate limiting has been avoided. But there is one problem, if I reload the web page before 10 sec, it gives an error undefined method `sort_by' for nil:NilClass. Kindly, correct me where am I wrong. Updated gist You can use those twitter credentials for executing it locally.

Comment: Ah well the rate limit still exists.

Comment: I updated the code using your original variable names, I think you should consider opening a new question if you wonder about a specific part of the code (also, your question probably was already asked before, so consider searching first).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would be nice if you could explain me a little about the code. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46659/discussion-between-sakshi-jain-and-user846250)